# Sorting almost sorted array

Tags: complexity-theory, data-structures

Encountered this question but I couldn't solve with the complexity they solved it:

Suppose I have an array that the first and last $\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}]{n} $ elements has $\frac{n}{5}$ inverted pairs, and the middle $n - 2\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}]{n}$ elemnts are sorted. What is the complexity of sorting the unsorted array?

They claim in the answer that sorting array with $I$ inversions is $O(n\log{\frac{n}{I}})$.Why?

Comment: Welcome to ComputerScience@SE. Please attribute quoted contents properly. (There is Markdown for *block quotes*: use `> ` line prefix or "the `"` button" in the post editor tool-bar.) Please check the problem statement: there are just so many values of $n$ where $\frac n 5$ does *not* exceed $1\ldots2 \times \sqrt n$.

Comment: I think $I$ refers to the [inversion count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)#Inversion_number) not to the number of swaps actually necessary to sort the array.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: Is the problem statement correct? As is you could just sort the $\sqrt{n}$ long prefixes and suffices in $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n} \log n)$ time leading to a linear algorithm.

Comment: That was my answer as well, this is why I'm so confused.

Comment: And do you mean "in $\mathcal{O}(n \log I)"$? $\mathcal{O}(n \log \frac{n}{I})$ doesn't make much sense, as then you could always sort either the array or the reversed array in linear time, giving a linear time sorting algorithm.

Comment: Why not? $ I < n$

Comment: Okay, it seems some nonstandard definition of an inversion is used here. Could you edit what you mean by "$I$ inversions" to the question?

Comment: note that for a valid question $n \geq 100$

Comment: @kelalaka `for a valid question n≥100` sure? For $n=400$, you get $2\sqrt 400 = 40$ "non-middle" elements - for $\frac n 5 = 80$ `inverted pairs`.

Comment: @greybeard I've looked for at least one element in the middle and $\frac{n}{5}$ is the whole left-right.

Comment: @kelalaka I don't understand *$\frac n 5$ is the whole left-right* - the question states `inverted pairs`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an array with a sequential range that covers all but k elements, and you know the range, then you sort the k elements in O (k log k), then merge two ranges that you know to be sorted in O (n). That sorts the whole array in O(n) as long as k is O (n / log  n).

In your case k = $O (n^{1/2})$ so clearly you can sort the array in O (n).

And you don't need to know the sorted range, because for large n we have n/2 inside the sorted range, so you can just count the elements in ascending / descending order from n/2 upwards / downwards.